# Passing parameter through powershell.exe

Tags: powershell

I have written this code

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [Int32]$BoxAlert,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [Int32]$MailAlert
)
)

powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden {
    if ($timeSpan.Days -ge $BoxAlert) {
        drawPopupBox $result
    }
    if ($timeSpan.Days -ge $MailAlert) {
        sendMail $result;
    }
}
```

How to pass that `$BoxAlert` and `$MailAlert` inside the `powershell.exe` scriptblock?

Comment: What is the purpose of launching PowerShell.exe inside powershell? Why not Invoke-Command or Start-Job?

Comment: As PowerShell is being called with a hidden window, I assume it's an attempt to hide/suppress the console output. If so using `Out-Null` or `>$null 2>&1` would be a much easier solution.

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What is the context this code is supposed to be running in? Why do you think you need `powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden`? Also, note that you have a spurious closing parenthesis after your `Param()` block.

Comment: Sorry for not elaborating,
actually i was creating a script which will calculate current up-time of an System. so, if the uptime is -ge 2 days then a popup message box should appear or if uptime is -ge 4 days then a mail shuold be sent to the user.
and i've used Powershell.exe so that the powershell window should not appear while running the script.

I wanted to pass that two parameters to script, so that the threshold limit of popup message box and mail alert can be modified through passing the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to add the -args switch after your scriptblock and a param() definition insides your script block. A simple version is

```
$x = bar    
powershell.exe -command {param($x) write-host "foo, $x"} -args $x
```

Gives the following output

```
foo, bar
```

Applying this logic to your code

```
 PowerShell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -command {
  param($BoxAlert, $MailAlert)

  if($timeSpan.Days -ge $BoxAlert)
  {
      drawPopupBox $result
  }
  if($timeSpan.Days -ge $MailAlert)
  {
        sendMail $result;
  }

} -args $BoxAlert, $MailAlert
```

Comment: `[CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][Int32]$BoxAlert,    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][Int32]$MailAlert     
)
PowerShell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden{
 param($BoxAlert, $MailAlert)
        if($timeSpan.Days -ge $BoxAlert)
 {
  drawPopupBox $result
 }
 if($timeSpan.Days -ge $MailAlert)
 {
  sendMail $result;
 }
} -args $BoxAlert,$MailAlert`

i have changed my code like this and its working now. am passing the value in the variables and the if block is working accordingly.